# Convert primary to logic partition (memory card)

Tags: partitioning, memory-card

I have a 1 GB memory card which had been set as primary partition. How do I change it to a logical partition?

I have already tried to

- Delete the contents with [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) Linux.
- Used [Paragon Partition Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragon_Software_Group#Storage_management) 10 to delete the contents and tried to change it to a logical partition.

But it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Create an extended partition to contain the logical partition first.